# MinGW linking with MSVC's dll library trouble (undefined references)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, mingw

This is might not a first time here question sounds like that but...
I know there are tools used for to get exported functions from .dll (.def generators) but there are useless (for me) because of mangled name format that compilers generate for functions are different.
**Is there any way (maybe some extra option in .def files) to tell mingw compiler: _ZN6IDcDrv6CreateEPKci (MingW's mangled name format) = ?Create@IDcDrv@@SAPAVDcDrv@@PBDH@Z (MSVC's mangled name format)????** (redirect lib.a's reference to dll's)
I'm talking about dlls with closed source, so I can't to compile a dll for mingw... or open source library which its building costs a lot of time and/or patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The MSVC name mangling is proprietary and undocumented.

Even if you could get the name mangling consistent across compilers, there are tons of other little differences that would make your linked code crash in all sorts of weird places (class layout, function calls, etc...).

If you need interoperability, write a C interface. 32-bit MinGW(-w64) GCC will even link to 32-bit MSVC C libraries and vice versa (if you include the necessary compiler libraries like libgcc or the security checking cookie thingie library MSVC adds to its code generation by default).

Comment: You are right. But what if function has this mangling format '_SomeFunction@16' while MinGW is looking for 'SomeFunction' (C declaration), is it possible to set a reference 'SomeFunction'->'_SomeFunction@16'? By the way, using this code `void (__stdcall*SomeFunction)() = (void (__stdcall*)())GetProcAddress(hModule, "_SomeFunction@16"); if(SomeFunction) SomeFunction();` does not crash application (no stack damage, etc).

Comment: Object layout and sometimes even object definition (in case of C++ stdlib types) is different between compilers, so you need to make sure you're not mixing them. In short: don't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way:

use objconv from https://www.agner.org/optimize to

- rename exported functions.
- convert object formats.
- ...

If you do this properly you'll get it linked.

Ensure that

- calling conventions
- object structures match

I've not tried this with c++, but who knows?